# PHP - Why is session still being created?

Tags: php

Good day, while doing my project, I did stuck on Login page.

This might be really trivial question or maybe even duplicate, but I can't find any solution online.

For some reason, my php script simply skips my login form and keeps making session and redirecting to index.php.

Here is my php script, for checking if email and password exist in databse:

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    require 'connect.php';

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $select_userdata = "select * from users where password ='$password' AND email = '$email'";

    $run_check = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $select_userdata);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_check);

    /**Error part**/
    if ($check_user == 0) {
        echo "<script>alert('Password or email is incorrect')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('login.php','_self')</script>";
    } else {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        echo "<script>alert ('You Have Been Logged in')</script>";
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
}
```

For some reason, script does not care, if I have email and password in database or not. It "pretends" that there is such email address and password, and skips to $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

My question is, what am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: did you call session_start() on this page? if not, it will only pretend its doing anything to $_SESSION

Comment: yes I did call session_start(), in start of function. For some reason I can't update code, but please, take my word for it. :)

Comment: because `$_SESSION['email'] = $email;` and the redirect are NOT inside the `if ($check_user == 0) {...}` so they always happen after the database read no matter what. Javascript alerts don't kill the process like calling `throw new Exception("");` in C#.  Either put an `exit()` in `if ($check_user == 0) {` or put the other stuff in `if ($check_user == 0) {`

Comment: or rather, put the other stuff in an else

Comment: it's really strange. I did put other stuff in else, but now it says, that email or password is incorrect. I did change code, should it look like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your logic not your code. $check_user is 0 or more there is no difference for your code. it always reach the *$_SESSION['email'] = $email*; line.
Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include'functions/dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    require 'functions/connect.php';
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $select_userdata = "select * from users where password ='$password' AND email = '$email'";


    $run_check = mysqli_query($dbconfig, $select_userdata);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_check);

    if ($check_user == 0)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Password or email is incorrect')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('login.php','_self')</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
        echo "<script>alert ('You Have Been Logged in')</script>";
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit;
    }
}
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
}
?>
```

Comment: For some reason, I still get error, that my Password or Email is incorrect.

Comment: There is no error, it just says, password or email is incorrect.
Basically - check_user == 0. But Email and password is 100% correct.

Could that be because I am saving password in database in md5 format?

Comment: Yes you should make password md5 before your sql.

Comment: Could you please show me how to do it in case of login? I did just try $passwordmd5 = md5($password); and then change my query: $select_userdata to select passwordmd5, but still no results.

Comment: I just fixed everything with your help. Thank you very much. Can I edit your code, to make it as Answer?

Comment: Yes you should.